# Get list of axis ticks with final formatting applied

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How do I get the **formatted** list of tick values from D3 as they will appear when the axis is rendered?

For example:

```
var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 0.061])
    .nice();

var xaxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .tickFormat(d3.format('.1%'));

console.log(x.ticks()); // [0, 0.005, 0.01, 0.015, 0.02, 0.025, 0.035...
console.log(xaxis.ticks()); //[10]
```

But what I really want is something like:

> ["0.0%", "0.5%", "1.0%", "1.5%", "2.0%", "2.5%", "3.0%", "3.5%", "4.0%", "4.5%", "5.0%", "5.5%", "6.0%", "6.5%"]

Answer (score 2):

This approach seems to work:

```
x.ticks().map(function(t) { return xaxis.tickFormat()(t); })
```

But it's a rather tortured syntax. If anyone knows a better answer using built-in methods, please post it.

This looked promising:

```
xaxis.tickValues()
```

But seems designed only for passing **in** values. If you call without parameters it returns null.