# How do I tell d3 to not repeat values in ticks?

Tags: d3.js

I made a histogram / bar graph. I read in my frequency data as integers and set up my y-axis like this:

```
var yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([300, 0]).domain([0, 2]);
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient(‘left’)
        .tickFormat(d3.format(,.0f));
```

Unfortunately, the y axis repeats each frequency several times as shown here:

[image]

How do I tell d3 to stop repeating y-values on the y-axis? I don’t want to use `.ticks(someNumber)` since I want to keep the number of ticks itself flexible.

Comment: Holy monkey, that picture appeared larger than I thought.

Comment: This is because you're setting the tick format to show only integer numbers; the tick values are in fact different. You'll have to use `.tickValues()` to set the tick values explicitly in this case.

Comment: but I'm parsing my frequency data with `parseInt(datum.frequency)` before charting. Shouldn't the frequencies be integers?

Comment: Well the scale isn't an integer scale. If you know that you'll have only the specific values you've posted here, then you can also specify the tick values explicitly.

Comment: if you want to know the final generated ticks you can use something like this answer and then perhaps check for uniqueness: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23297504/get-list-of-axis-ticks-with-final-formatting-applied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use .ticks(n) instead of tickFormat() on your axis. The ticks() function defines how many ticks d3 should target - it's not always exactly that number. It chooses the most sane division unit on its own. n is 10 by default but you could change it depending on the domain, so for the example data you could set it to 3 (0,1,2). You could theoretically also use it on data enter.

Is your graph's range/height dynamic depending on data? In most cases you don't want that as it's unpredictable. And if you set your graph's height explicitly anyway you DO want to limit the number of ticks and labels to a number best suiting that size.

You might also want to look into https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#linear_nice . That allows you to define rules for your ticks.

Answer (score 3):

I needed mine to be dynamic, this worked for me: [Version 4]

```
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

 var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
        .scale(y)
        .tickFormat(d3.format("%d"));

      // Reset the axes domains with new data
      y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.value; })]);


  if (y.domain() [1] < 10) {
            yAxis.ticks(y.domain()[1])

            // 2 ticks
            //yAxis.tickValues(y.domain());
        }

        // Add the y-axis with a transition
        yAxisG
          .transition()
            .duration(500)
            .call(yAxis);
```